# How can I handle a > 22 column table with Slick using nested tuples or HLists?

Tags: scala, tuples, slick, scala-2.11

I'm new to Scala (using 2.10) and Slick (using 2.0-M2). I see that one of the ways to get around the 22 column limit for tables in Slick is to use nested tuples. I can't figure out how to do that, despite finding [this partial code on GitHub](https://github.com/slick/slick/commit/7f8668e49da34cf0cb52ac21a6f5b46d0b0fdb47).

Current dev branch Scala (2.11-M5) supports case classes with more than 22 elements, but not tuples with arity > 22. And Slick is not yet distributed for Scala 2.11 pre-releases. How can I define a 33 column table (and have it work with all Slick's syntactic sugar)?

N.B., I'm trying to support an existing schema and can't change the table normalization.

Comment: Won't help you, but related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19593137/can-i-output-a-collection-instead-of-a-tuple-in-scalding-map-method (putting it there because if somebody will comeup with answer to this question it could answer to that guy as well).

Comment: This related question has lots of useful information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906684/scala-slick-method-i-can-not-understand-so-far

Answer (score 6):

Here I write a post to give out the solution. Here is the link: https://lihaimei.wordpress.com/2016/03/30/slick-1-fix-more-than-22-columns-case/

I draw some graphs and use different colors to help you understand fast.

To summarize, I use additional case Class to package some columns to one, which will not influence real physical columns. And then when we use projection to map to a custom type, we involve tuple back. This is a hack solution, but it is easily to fix Scala programming language's limit where the size of tuples should be less than 22.

Answer (score 2):

The test code you linked to is outdated. If you don't use mappings for your tables, it's straight-forward: The type of `*` corresponds to the return type you get when querying the table, whether it is a single tuple, an HList, or nested tuples. Since Slick 2.1 this works for all operations. (In 2.0 it was not supported for the `*` projection, so you had to define an alternate projection and override `create_*`.) See [here](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/2.1/slick-testkit/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/slick/testkit/tests/JdbcMapperTest.scala#L312-337) for an HList example.

If you want to map the `*` projection to a custom type, you also use the `<>` operator as for a single tuple but you don't get the convenience of the `tupled` and `unapply` methods that are automatically generated for case classes, so you have to write the two mapping functions (from the unmapped to the mapped type and back) manually as shown [here](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/2.1/slick-testkit/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/slick/testkit/tests/JdbcMapperTest.scala#L129-141). Note that Scala 2.11 does not improve this situation. While it allows case classes with more than 22 fields, there are no corresponding `Function` types for arities > 22, so you still can't use `tupled` and `unapply`.

As an alternative to writing these functions, you can define a *lifted* type corresponding to your mapped type as [explained in the manual](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/userdefined.html#monomorphic-case-classes). This is especially useful when you have nested case classes (of <= 22 fields each) for your mapped type. You only have to define *separate* mappings for each case class and they will automatically compose when you use them in a `*` projection (or any other place in a projection or query).

Comment: I can't make this custom case class mapping (based on the test) to work. I've opened a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28305023/custom-mapping-to-nested-case-class-structure-in-slick-more-than-22-columns