# choosing a shapeless HList instead of a case class

Tags: scala, functional-programming, shapeless, hlist

What are the advantages of using a shapeless HList over a case class in Scala? In what situations would you *not* want to use a HList?

Comment: You could reframe this as case classes vs. tuples and the answer would be essentially the same.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to read these questions first:

- [Are HLists nothing more than a convoluted way of writing tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825129/are-hlists-nothing-more-than-a-convoluted-way-of-writing-tuples)
- [How can I use the new Slick 2.0 HList to overcome 22 column limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555304/how-can-i-use-the-new-slick-2-0-hlist-to-overcome-22-column-limit)

Essentially `case classes` are `tuples` underneath, which in turn map to a `Java classes`. However `HList` is a `List like` data structure. So you may have to traverse the list to access a particular member `HList`. This is more costly than using a case class member or a tuple member.

Comment: also switching from case classes to extensible records may have performance implications, see the following benchmark:
https://github.com/eugengarkusha/record-vs-caseclass-element-access-benchmark