# Map table with more than 22 columns to Scala case class by Slick 2.1.0

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, playframework-2.3, scala-2.11

I'm using Scala 2.11, Slick 2.1.0-M2, PlayFramework 2.3.1.

I need to map 25 columns table to Scala's case class.

For example I have this case class:

```
case class Test(f1: Long, f2: String, f3: String, f4: String, f5: String, 
                f6: String, f7: String, f8: String, f9: String, f10: String, 
                f11: String, f12: String, f13: String, f14: String, f15: String, 
                f16: String, f17: String, f18: String, f19: String, f20: String, 
                f21: String, f22: String, f23: Float, f24: Float, f25: String)
```

I read that it is possible to write custom `Shape` ([proof](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0-RC1/userdefined.html#polymorphic-types-e-g-custom-tuple-types-or-hlists)), but any my attempts to realize it is fails.

Please help me map this case class to table.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19636611/how-can-i-handle-a-22-column-table-with-slick-using-nested-tuples-or-hlists

Comment: It's not duplication, because nothing about `Shape` there.

Comment: Not a duplication because this question asks for case classes > 22 columns, which is a new feature in Scala 2.11.

Comment: any update here, maybe in Slick 3.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a good solution to this question for current slick version. You can pack some fields into one case class.

Please refer to this test case.

https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/2.1.0-RC1/slick-testkit/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/slick/testkit/tests/JdbcMapperTest.scala#L99

Comment: I saw this solution and I think it is very bad to maintain. I think implement `Shape` trait be much better. But I can't make it robust.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this could be done via `HList` like this

```
def * = (col1 :: col2 :: .. :: HNil).shaped <> (
{ case x => new YYY(x(0), x(1), ..)}, 
{ x: YYY => Option(x.col1 :: x.col2 :: .. :: HNil)}
)
```

I've written an macro to do the mapping, you may take a look at this
https://github.com/jilen/slickext

Answer (score 0):

I have a HListCaseClassShape [that works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40543310/trying-to-make-a-hcons-list-caseclassshape) exactly like the CaseClassShape but without the 22 column limit: [here](https://gist.github.com/deusaquilus/5b52b82598c534ca09119efcf0acbc50). You could then map it to your table like this: `def * = MyHListCaseClassShape(f1, f2, f3...)` (see the Pair * example [here](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/userdefined.html)). Not sure if it'll work with Slick 2 but might be worth a shot.