# Custom mapping to nested case class structure in Slick (more than 22 columns)

Tags: scala, slick

I'm trying to map a DB row with more than 22 columns to a case class tree.
I'd rather not using HList as I don't want to work with that API, and also for some exponential compilation time feedbacks that I've read somewhere...

I have read this thread answered by Stefan Zeiger: [How can I handle a > 22 column table with Slick using nested tuples or HLists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19636611/how-can-i-handle-a-22-column-table-with-slick-using-nested-tuples-or-hlists)

I've seen this test which shows how to define a custom mapping function and I'd like to do that:

https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/2.1/slick-testkit/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/slick/testkit/tests/JdbcMapperTest.scala#L129-141

```
def * = (
        id,
        (p1i1, p1i2, p1i3, p1i4, p1i5, p1i6),
        (p2i1, p2i2, p2i3, p2i4, p2i5, p2i6),
        (p3i1, p3i2, p3i3, p3i4, p3i5, p3i6),
        (p4i1, p4i2, p4i3, p4i4, p4i5, p4i6)
      ).shaped <> ({ case (id, p1, p2, p3, p4) =>
        // We could do this without .shaped but then we'd have to write a type annotation for the parameters
        Whole(id, Part.tupled.apply(p1), Part.tupled.apply(p2), Part.tupled.apply(p3), Part.tupled.apply(p4))
      }, { w: Whole =>
        def f(p: Part) = Part.unapply(p).get
        Some((w.id, f(w.p1), f(w.p2), f(w.p3), f(w.p4)))
      })
```

The problem is that I can't make it!

I've tried by smaller steps.

```
class UserTable(tag: Tag) extends TableWithId[User](tag,"USER") {
  override def id = column[String]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  def role = column[UserRole.Value]("role", O.NotNull)
  def login = column[String]("login", O.NotNull)
  def password = column[String]("password", O.NotNull)
  def firstName = column[String]("first_name", O.NotNull)
  def lastName = column[String]("last_name", O.NotNull)
  //
  def * = (id, role, login, password, firstName, lastName) <> (User.tupled,User.unapply)
  //
  def login_index = index("idx_user_login", login, unique = true)
}
```

It seems that when I call

```
(id, (firstName, lastName)).shaped
```

The type is `ShapedValue[(Column[String], (Column[String], Column[String])), Nothing]`

While this one seems to work fine

```
(id, firstName, lastName).shaped
```

The U type parameter is not `Nothing` but as expected `(String, String, String)`

I don't really understand how all the Slick internals are working. Can someone explain me why I can't make my code work? Is there a missing import or something?

I guess I need to get a value of type

```
ShapedValue[(Column[String], (Column[String], Column[String])), (String, (String, String))]
```

but I don't know why it returns me `Nothing` and don't really understand where these implicit `Shape` parameters come from...

What I want is just to be able to easily split my column into 2 case classes

Thanks

Comment: This question was also later answered in a duplicate question. For Slick 3.2.3: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49659436/1080804

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Also, have the same problem with the 22 columns limitation, the [test case](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/2.1/slick-testkit/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/slick/testkit/tests/JdbcMapperTest.scala#L129-141) helps very much. Not sure why the example code not working for you, the following code works fine for me,

```
case class UserRole(var role: String, var extra: String)
case class UserInfo(var login: String, var password: String, var firstName: String, var lastName: String)

case class User(id: Option[String], var info: UserInfo, var role: UserRole)

class UserTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "USER") {

  def id = column[String]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  def role = column[String]("role", O.NotNull)
  def extra = column[String]("extra", O.NotNull)
  def login = column[String]("login", O.NotNull)
  def password = column[String]("password", O.NotNull)
  def firstName = column[String]("first_name", O.NotNull)
  def lastName = column[String]("last_name", O.NotNull)

  /** Projection */
  def * = (
    id,
    (login, password, firstName, lastName),
    (role, extra)
  ).shaped <> (

  { case (id, userInfo, userRole) =>
    User(Option[id], UserInfo.tupled.apply(userInfo), UserRole.tupled.apply(userRole))
  },
  { u: User =>
      def f1(p: UserInfo) = UserInfo.unapply(p).get
      def f2(p: UserRole) = UserRole.unapply(p).get
      Some((u.id.get, f1(u.info), f2(u.role)))
  })

  def login_index = index("id_user_login", login, unique = true)
}
```

Comment: thanks, it seems you are right it works fine. It's just so easy to make a typo when you have very large tuples ;) I think I had a problem with type inference and maybe a typo so I decided to go step by step, providing types explicitly at each step and now it works

Comment: thanks, this worked for me too. Additionally I found a very good example on https://lihaimei.wordpress.com/2016/03/30/slick-1-fix-more-than-22-columns-case/

Answer (score 9):

As Izongren answered it works fine, but it can be hard to write such code as it's annoying to work with very long tuples... I decided to do it "step by step" and always providing types explicitly to avoid type inference problemes and now it works fine.

```
case class Patient(
                    id: String = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString,
                    companyScopeId: String,
                    assignedToUserId: Option[String] = None,
                    info: PatientInfo
                    ) extends ModelWithId



case class PatientInfo(
                        firstName: Option[String] = None,
                        lastName: Option[String] = None,
                        gender: Option[Gender.Value] = None,
                        alias: Option[String] = None,
                        street: Option[String] = None,
                        city: Option[String] = None,
                        postalCode: Option[String] = None,
                        phone: Option[String] = None,
                        mobilePhone: Option[String] = None,
                        email: Option[String] = None,
                        age: Option[AgeRange.Value] = None,
                        companySeniority: Option[CompanySeniorityRange.Value] = None,
                        employmentContract: Option[EmploymentContract.Value] = None,
                        socialStatus: Option[SocialStatus.Value] = None,
                        jobTitle: Option[String] = None
                        )

class PatientTable(tag: Tag) extends TableWithId[Patient](tag,"PATIENT") {
  override def id = column[String]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  def companyScopeId = column[String]("company_scope_id", O.NotNull)
  def assignedToUserId = column[Option[String]]("assigned_to_user_id", O.Nullable)

  def firstName = column[Option[String]]("first_name", O.Nullable)
  def lastName = column[Option[String]]("last_name", O.Nullable)
  def gender = column[Option[Gender.Value]]("gender", O.Nullable)
  def alias = column[Option[String]]("alias", O.Nullable)
  def street = column[Option[String]]("street", O.Nullable)
  def city = column[Option[String]]("city", O.Nullable)
  def postalCode = column[Option[String]]("postal_code", O.Nullable)
  def phone = column[Option[String]]("phone", O.Nullable)
  def mobilePhone = column[Option[String]]("mobile_phone", O.Nullable)
  def email = column[Option[String]]("email", O.Nullable)
  def age = column[Option[AgeRange.Value]]("age", O.Nullable)
  def companySeniority = column[Option[CompanySeniorityRange.Value]]("company_seniority", O.Nullable)
  def employmentContract = column[Option[EmploymentContract.Value]]("employment_contract", O.Nullable)
  def socialStatus = column[Option[SocialStatus.Value]]("social_status", O.Nullable)
  def jobTitle = column[Option[String]]("job_title", O.Nullable)
  def role = column[Option[String]]("role", O.Nullable)



  private type PatientInfoTupleType = (Option[String], Option[String], Option[Gender.Value], Option[String], Option[String], Option[String], Option[String], Option[String], Option[String], Option[String], Option[AgeRange.Value], Option[CompanySeniorityRange.Value], Option[EmploymentContract.Value], Option[SocialStatus.Value], Option[String])
  private type PatientTupleType = (String, String, Option[String], PatientInfoTupleType)
  //
  private val patientShapedValue = (id, companyScopeId, assignedToUserId,
    (
      firstName, lastName, gender, alias, street, city, postalCode,
      phone, mobilePhone,email, age, companySeniority, employmentContract, socialStatus, jobTitle
      )
    ).shaped[PatientTupleType]
  //
  private val toModel: PatientTupleType => Patient = { patientTuple =>
    Patient(
      id = patientTuple._1,
      companyScopeId = patientTuple._2,
      assignedToUserId = patientTuple._3,
      info = PatientInfo.tupled.apply(patientTuple._4)
    )
  }
  private val toTuple: Patient => Option[PatientTupleType] = { patient =>
    Some {
      (
        patient.id,
        patient.companyScopeId,
        patient.assignedToUserId,
        (PatientInfo.unapply(patient.info).get)
        )
    }
  }

  def * = patientShapedValue <> (toModel,toTuple)
}
```

Comment: In the mess created by Slick, this is beautiful!

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use this way

```
class UserTable(tag: Tag) extends TableWithId[User](tag,"USER") {
  def id = column[String]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  def role = column[String]("role", O.NotNull)
  def extra = column[String]("extra", O.NotNull)
  def login = column[String]("login", O.NotNull)
  def password = column[String]("password", O.NotNull)
  def firstName = column[String]("first_name", O.NotNull)
  def lastName = column[String]("last_name", O.NotNull)

  def loginMap = (login, password, firstName, lastName) <> (UserInfo.tupled, UserInfo.unapply)

  def roleMap = (role, extra) <> (Role.tupled, Role.unapply)

  override def * = (id, roleMap, loginMap) <> (User.tupled,User.unapply)

  def login_index = index("idx_user_login", login, unique = true)
}
```