# Can we create a type alias for a tuple dynamically?

Tags: scala, scala-macros, shapeless

Suppose I have a tuple

```
val myTuple: (String,Int,String,...,Boolean) = ("",0,"",..,true)
```

I can write a type alias

```
type MyType = (String,Int,String,...,Boolean)
val myTuple: MyType = ("",0,"",..,true)
```

Can I write this type alias dynamically? Is there a way to not be explicit in this type aliasing and let the compiler find the type itself to associate to the alias?

For exemple something like

```
case class MyCaseClass(x: String,y: Int,z:String,...,zz:Boolean)

type MyDynamicTupleType = MyCaseClass.tupled.parameter1.type
```

Not sure this is possible or if this is very useful, just find out that with very long tuples writing aliases is very boring and is just boilerplate ([exemple here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28408343/82609)).

Open for macro-based or shapeless solutions

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. But you may find Shapeless useful for this. See https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#generic-representation-of-sealed-families-of-case-classes

Comment: yes it seems so. Open to a shapeless exemple achieving this too :)

Comment: I don' t think you can do it at runtime ( Barring Shapeless ). But still you can try doing this with Scala Macros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining a couple of pieces from shapeless gets us most of the way there - `Generic` to represent our `case class` as a `HList`, `Tupler` to represent the `HList` as a tuple:

```
sealed trait GenericAsTuple[G] {
  type Out
}
object GenericAsTuple {
  implicit def fromGenericAndTupler[G, T <: HList, O](
    implicit g: Generic[G]{type Repr = T}, t: Tupler[T] {type Out = O}) =
      new GenericAsTuple[G]{type Out = O}
  def apply[G](implicit g: GenericAsTuple[G]): GenericAsTuple[G]{
    type Out = g.Out} = g
}

val myGat = GenericAsTuple[MyCaseClass]
type MyDynamicTupleType = myGat.Out
```

I'm not aware of a way (short of macros) to avoid taking two steps to invoke - `myGat` needs to be a stable value to be able to declare a type alias, we can't just do `GenericAsTuple[MyCaseClass].Out`.