# 22 Column limit for procedures

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

How can we overcome the 22 limit when calling procedures with Slick?

We currently have:

```
val q3 = sql"""call getStatements(${accountNumber})""".as[Transaction]
```

The problem is that we have to return more than 22 columns and Transaction case class cannot have more than 22 columns since when we do JSONFormat we get an error:

```
[error] E:\IdeaProjects\admin\Transaction.scala:59: No unapply or unapplySeq function found
[error]   implicit val jsonFormat = Json.format[Transaction]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: which version of scala are you using?

Comment: Over 22 columns you could use HList here is a gist: 
https://gist.github.com/davegurnell/8dd7d01eff8e59877abb

Comment: Do not know about slick, but you can process more than 22 fields in the JSON with the help of https://github.com/xdotai/play-json-extensions

Comment: Important question - can you modify your `Transaction` case class?

Comment: Yes sure, I can do whatever I want with that class.

Comment: See here for Slick 3.2.3: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36618280/slick-codegen-tables-with-22-columns/49659436#49659436
  There are many duplicates of this question

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Alright - so if you can actually modify your `Transaction` case class than there is a better solution than `HList` (which to be honest may be a little cumbersome to operate with later on).

So here is the thing: let's imagine you have `User` table with following attributes:

- id
- name
- surname
- faculty
- finalGrade
- street
- number
- city
- postCode

Above columns may not make sense but let's use them as example. The most straightforward way to deal with above is to create a case class:

```
case class User(
   id: Long,
   name: String,
   ...  // rest of the attributes here
   postCode: String)
```

which would be mapped from table on the application side.

Now what you can also do is to do this:

```
case class Address(street: String, number: String, city: String, postCode: String)

case class UniversityInfo(faculty: String, finalGrade: Double)

case class User(id: Long, name: String, surname: String, uniInfo: UniversityInfo, address: Address)
```

This composition will help you to avoid problem with too many columns (which is basically problem with too many attributes in your case class/tuple). **Apart from that - I would argue that it is always (very often?) beneficial to do this if you have many columns - if for nothing else than simply for readability purposes.**

How to do the mapping

```
class User(tag: Tag) extends Table(tag, "User") {

  // cricoss info
  def id = column[Long]("id")
  def name = column[String]("name")

  // ... all the other fields
  def postCode = column[String]("postCode")

  def * = (id, name, surname, uniInfoProjection, addressProjection) <>((User.apply _).tupled, User.unapply)

  def uniInfoProjection = (faculty, finalGrade) <>((UniversityInfo.apply _).tupled, UniversityInfo.unapply)

  def addressProjection = (street, number, city, city) <>((Address.apply _).tupled, Address.unapply)
}
```

The same can be done with custom `SQL` mapping.

```
implicit val getUserResult = GetResult(r => 
    User(r.nextLong, r.nextString, r.nextString, 
         UniversityInfo(r.nextString, r.nextDouble),
         Adress(r.nextString, r.nextString, r.nextString, r.nextString))
)
```

---

So to put things simply - try to segregate your fields into multiple nested case classes and your problem should go away (with added benefit of improved readability). If you do that approaching tuple/case class limit should virtually never be a problem (and you shouldn't even need to use `HList`).

Comment: Excellent that's exactly what we use for our other models. But can I do that when the result is from a procedure as well? Can I get the result of a procedure into a class that extends Table class?

Comment: Sure, as long as `Slick` is concerned - it is just a query result.

Comment: Can I get the result of a procedure into a class that extends Table class? If yes that's awesome.

Comment: That's confusing question - `Table` class is for specifying mapping, it is not for representing actual db tuples. You normally have a pair: - class extending `Table` (mapping definition) and a `case class` for representing db tuples (it doesn't need to be case class - but most often it is)

Comment: Yes we do that automatically for all our tables using the Generator. We modified that to our needs and it works really really good. But for the results from the procedure I just used a simple `case class` and it worked really well.