# How to overcome the 22 columns limit in Slick 3.2?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, slick-3.0

I switched from Java/EJB to Scala/Play/Slick, and in the middle of my project I found out that there's a limitation in Slick 3.2 to have more than 22 columns. What is the best workaround? I don't want to use external libraries [such as this one](https://github.com/underscoreio/slickless) where I may not know what to do if they break in production.

Comment: This question has been asked before. See solution for Slick 3.2.3 here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49659436/1080804

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slick codegen & tables with > 22 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36618280/slick-codegen-tables-with-22-columns)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [22 Column limit for procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42399431/22-column-limit-for-procedures)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is perhaps an approach that would solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42414478/2239369

I am yet to find out a situation in which this limit would effectively be of any relevance (unless you use generated code that you cannot change).